# Why does Eclipse complain about unsafe type casting?

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection, type-safety

Consider the following code:

```
public static <T extends SomeObject> List<T> getByClassName(String className) throws GetRecordsException {
    try {
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName(className).asSubclass(SomeObject.class);
        return getByClassName(clazz);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new GetRecordsException("Failed to get class forName: " + className, e);
    }
}
```

Eclipse is highlighting the cast `(Class<T>)` with the following message:

`Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#2-of ? extends SomeObject> to Class<T>`

Why is this, considering that `T` is supposed to be guaranteed to extend from `SomeObject` in the method signature? What scenario might exist where this would be unsafe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *caller* of `getByClassName` specifies `T` to be any subclass of `SomeObject`, but that doesn't have to be the same subclass as the one named by `className`.  Think of `<T extends SomeObject>` as indicating that the type variable `T` is another argument passed into the method call.

So for example, an unsafe usage would be `foo.<SomeObjectSubclass1>getByClassName("SomeObjectSubclass2")` -- that syntax is how you specify type arguments explicitly, instead of letting them be inferred -- and then that'd return a `List<SomeObjectSubclass1>` that actually contained `SomeObjectSubclass2`, and everything would be a disaster.

What you could do safely is let `clazz` be a `Class<? extends SomeObject>`, and then return a `List<? extends SomeObject`.